# Pass a variable into a filter - R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a sample of the dataset that I have. I am looking to find the state that has the maximum number of stores. In this case, CA and also see how many IDs come from that state

```
| ID | | State | | Stores| 
| -- | |------ | | ----- | 
|a11 | | CA    | | 16585 | 
|a12 | | CA    | | 45552 | 
|a13 | | AK    | | 7811  |
|a14 | | MA    | | 4221  |
```

I have this code using dplyr

```
max_state <- df  %>%
    group_by(State)  %>%
    summarise(total_stores = sum(Stores))  %>%
    top_n(1)  %>%
    select(State)
```

This gives me "CA"

Can I use this variable "max(state)" to pass through a filter and use summarise(n()) to count the number of Ids for CA?

Comment: It's better to provide `dput(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways:

```
# this takes your max_state (CA) and brings in the parts of 
# your original table that have the same State
max_state %>% 
  left_join(df) %>%
  summarize(n = n())

# filter the State in df to match the State in max_state
df %>%
  filter(State == max_state$State) %>%
  summarize(n = n())


# Add Stores_total for each State, only keep the State rows which
# match that of the max State, and count the # of IDs therein
df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate(Stores_total = sum(Stores)) %>%
  filter(Stores_total == max(Stores_total)) %>% 
  count(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine more operations into one `summarize` call that will be applied to the same group:

```r
df |>
  group_by(State) |>
  summarize(gsum = sum(Stores), nids = n()) |>
  filter(gsum == max(gsum))

##>+ # A tibble: 1 × 3
##>  State  gsum  nids
##>  <chr> <dbl> <int>
##>1 CA    62137     2
```

Where the dataset `df` is obtained by:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a11", "a12","a13", "a14"),
                 State = c("CA", "CA", "AK", "MA"),
                 Stores = c(16585, 45552, 7811, 4221))
```